# Halt javascript execution until promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, jasmine, protractor

I have a specific use case where in test code I want to fetch a tables headers (async) and then dynamically create getters on a javascript object. The syntax that I would like to use in my test is `antenneTable.row(0).getAzimut();`. The problem I am having is that `antenneTable.row(0);` returns a promise and so getAzimut is not yet defined on that object.

I know how to fix it if I use antennetable.row(0).then() but would like to keep the syntax.

Thanks in advance

This is my code :

Row.js

```
'use strict';

var Row = function (row, classes) {
var outer = this;
    function camelCase(input) {
        return input.toLowerCase().replace(/-(.)/g, function(match, group1) {
            return group1.toUpperCase();
    })}

    for(var i =0 ; i< classes.length; i ++){
        var methodName = camelCase("get-"+classes[i]);
        (function(index) {
            outer[methodName] = function () {
                return row.all(by.tagName('td')).get(index).getText();
            }
        })(i);
    }

};

module.exports = Row;
```

Table.js

```
'use strict';
var Row = require('./row.js');

var Table = function (tableElement) {
    var headElement = tableElement.element(by.css('thead'));
    var bodyElement = tableElement.element(by.css('tbody'));

    this.row = function (index) {
        return headElement.all(by.css('th')).map(function (th) {
            return th.getAttribute('class');
        }).then(function (clazzes) {
            var rows = bodyElement.all(by.css('tr'));
            return new Row(rows.get(index), clazzes);
        })
    };
};

module.exports = Table;
```

MyTestClass.js

```
'use strict';

describe('dossier map', function(){
    var mainPage = require('../../pages/mainpage.js');
    var DossierDetailPage = require('../../pages/dossier/dossier-detail.js');
    var Table = require('../../pages/table.js');
    var dossierDetailPage = new DossierDetailPage();

    afterEach(function() {
        resetData();
        mainPage.logout();
    });


    it('antenne details popup verschijnt', function() {
        // TODO Activate test in Firefox and IE
        if (!browser.isFirefox && !browser.isIE) {
            mainPage.goTo('admin', 'admin');
            mainPage.dossiers().byIndex(7).openDetail();
            dossierDetailPage.zoomOut(5);

            var popoverElement = element(by.css('#popover .popover'));
            browser.driver.wait(function() {
                return popoverElement.isPresent().then(function(isDisplayed){
                    if (isDisplayed) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        dossierDetailPage.klikOpAntenneCluster(11);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
            var antenneTable = new Table(popoverElement.element(by.css('table')));

            expect(antenneTable.row(0).getAzimut()).toBe('115');



        }
    }, 120000);


});
```

Comment: If you get a promise, you can set the code to occur when it is done. See for instance [this link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/). After seeing your edit that you already know; you cannot keep your current syntax in the scenario you describe.

Comment: Yeah I know how to fix it if I use then() but would love to keep the current syntax and make protractor somehow wait until antenneTable.row(0) is resolved without adding the syntax sugar

Comment: @Arno_Geismar. is that nodejs hosted script?

Comment: in essence wait until the promise has returned a value

Comment: @JossefHarush yes its a node hosted script. we are using grunt to run our end to end tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Async/Await

There's this library called [async/await](https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait) (*inspired by `C#` version 5*)

this makes your promisable code to **look and feel synchronized**

**e.g.**

```
var Q = require("q");
var async = require('asyncawait/async');
var await = require('asyncawait/await');

function delay(millis) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    setTimeout(deferred.resolve, millis);
    return deferred.promise;
}

async(function () {
    console.log('message 1');
    await(delay(100));
    console.log('message 2');
})();
```

- must be hosted on NodeJS environment
- awesome coding user experience

Comment: I will try this aproach and get back to you

Comment: @Arno_Geismar; great! iv'e used it in https://github.com/Jossef/amigos/tree/master/libs and it's awesome!

Comment: I have tried your aproach but am still getting the same result.

Comment: can you add a `gist` / `pastebin` of what you've tried?

Comment: use it like this: https://gist.github.com/Jossef/f12e5ea1ac4fc561d9be you need to wrap you functionality with custom promises

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80999/discussion-between-jossef-harush-and-arno-geismar).

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be to not return the object but a proxy of this object and resolve your method only when you promise has been resolved.

You could take a look at https://github.com/tvcutsem/harmony-reflect

Comment: Can you use the proxy methods even when the methods are not known in advance ( they are being created dynamically depending on what the promise returnes)